# Estack MEAN -> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova

I have an app with angular front end and nodeJS back end.

ng serve, works fine, but `cordova run --debug`, I have an error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users/singin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED polyfills.d15cf5b3fe5c097b06a9.js:1
```

My English is not very good, please, you excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

I having problem in my front end. 
the apk could not resolve the localhost address.
the solution was to deliver the exact ip of my server where I made the requests.

Ej:
`getUsersApi(): Observable {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users', this.headersAuth);
  }

getUsersApi(): Observable {
    return this.http.get('http://192.123.1.65:3000/users', this.headersAuth);
  }`
Regards.